# ASP.NET MVC. How to suppress showing default culture in URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-mvc-routing

here is question.
I have an localized asp.net mvc website.
Localization done by next steps:
1. for each route I automatically add an {culture} url segment with default value to "ru".

I want my urls to be with culture only for foreign cultures.
For example:

```
http://mysite.com/ua/contacts - ukrainian
http://mysite.com/fr/contacts - francis
http://mysite.com/contacts - russian
```

I can't arrive this, because @Url.Action method always returns url with culture, even then it is a default culture.
Help me please!

Comment: Can you show us your route configuration?

Comment: `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "HomePage",
                url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", culture="ru" }
            );`

Comment: Add `culture` as an optional parameter `culture= UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: If you set culture=UrlParameter.Optional then you will not be able to access home page. As I see it is a very generic situation but I can't find any info about how to implement that, using standart ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Ilya answered your another question similar to this. Take a look, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103621/asp-net-mvc-routing-and-url-building/16125500#16125500

Answer (score 0):

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

as base you can find solution right here
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs
and on msdn
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Greate ) Can you show me please where is answer on that pages?

Comment: cannot try right now but direction should be like this routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}" + MakeSomeLogic + "/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default2",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                            // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }   // Parameter defaults
);